# Laravel array session

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-8

I need to be able to use an array in session please. I want to store diffrents *candidate_id* to find the candidates later.

`CandidateController` :

```
public function search(Request $request)
{

$data=$request->validate([
    'keyword' => 'required',
    'word' => 'required',]);
$keyword= $data['keyword'];
$key= $data['key'];
$candidate = candidate::where($key, $keyword)->get();
return view('candidate.list', compact('candidate'));
 }
```

what are the changes that I should do to make a session array that contains [candidate's ids]
and then finding those $candidate using these ids, and return `view('candidate.list', compact('candidate'))` ? is it possible ?

Comment: Question is not clear. First;  What is the `$key= $data['key'];` line for? What are you trying to achieve? You can store your array data in session and push a new item to it `session()->push('candidate_ids', $candidate_id)` but I don't understand to context.

Answer (score 1):

$candidate = candidate::where($key, $keyword)->get();
after this line loop through the `$candidate`.

```
 $ids = [];
    foreach ($candidate as $obj){ 
     
      $ids = $obj->candidate_id; 
}

session()->push('candidate_ids', $ids);

return view('candidate.list', compact('candidate'));
```

when you need to get this array from the session just

```
@foreach (Session::get('candidate_ids') as $id)
    {{$id}}
@endforeach
```